# Integrate an Intgegraloperator

Tags: integration

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define

$\mathbb{P}_n([0,1]):=${$p:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}, p(x)= \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k:(a_k)_{k=0}^n \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$}.

For $\mathbb{P}_n([0,1])$ and $\mathbb{P}_{2n+1}([0,1])$ we have the max-norm.

Compute the derivative of the following function:

$J: \mathbb{P}_n([0,1]) \to \mathbb{P}_{2n+1}([0,1]), p \to (x\to \int_0^x p(t)^2 dt) $

We have the following definition to check if a function is differentiable:

Definition: $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-A_x(h)}{||h||} = 0$ where $A_x \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y).$

$J(p(x)+h(x))-J(p(x) = \int_0^x(p(t)+h(t))^2dt - \int_0^xp(t)^2dt$

$= 2\int_0^xp(t)h(t)dt+\int_0^xh(t)^2dt$

How can I compute $A_x$? In the end this should be the derivate of the function $J$ right? If the limit is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your notations are not correct. Here $J$ maps $X=\mathbb P_n$ to $Y=\mathbb P_{2n+1}$. The derivative of $J$ at  a point $f \in X$ is a linear map $A_f$ from $X$ to $Y$. Verify that $A_f(h) (x)=2f(x)\int_0^{x}h(t)dt$ is the required linear map. If you understand the notations correctly it is easy to verify this.

Comment: How did you compute $A_f(h)(x)$? And to verify $A_f(h)(x)$ I have to solve following equation, right?:

$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \frac{J(p(x)+h(x))-J(p(x) -A_{p(x)}(h))}{||h||}$